# Парсер данных из сайта новостей "gorod48.ru" на lxml

Tags: python, парсер, lxml

Пробую парсить данные из сайта новостей "gorod48.ru" в формате `'Название новости', 'Ссылка', 'Количество комментариев'`. Там где нет комментариев должно проставляться `0`, а там где есть, соответственно должно быть их количество. Работаю на `lxml. Колличество комментариев не соответсвует новости`

```py
import requests
from lxml import html

url = 'https://gorod48.ru/news/date/05.07.2020/'
page = requests.get(url)
tree = html.fromstring(page.text)
for trees in tree:
    name=trees.xpath('.//div[@class="newsFeedList"]//div[@class="item link"]/a/text()')
    link_news = trees.xpath('.//div[@class="newsFeedList"]//div[@class="comment"]/a/@href')
    count_comments = trees.xpath('.//div[@class="newsFeedList"]//div[@class="item"]')
```

**Далее должно быть так:**

- *Если к новости есть комментарии:*
  то добавить количество комментариев к конкретно этой новости в список
- *Иначе:*
  то добавить количество "0" к конкретно этой новости в список

И все данные добавить в CSV

[image: То что выдает программа]

[image: то что на сайте]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import requests
from lxml import html
url = 'https://gorod48.ru/news/date/05.07.2020/'
page = requests.get(url)
tree = html.fromstring(page.text)
name=tree.xpath('.//div[@class="newsFeedList"]//div[@class="item link"]/a/text()')
link_news =tree.xpath('.//div[@class="newsFeedList"]//div[@class="item link"]/a/@href')
link_comments = tree.xpath('.//div[@class="newsFeedList"]//div[@class="comment"]/a/@href')
count_comments = tree.xpath('.//div[@class="newsFeedList"]//div[@class="comment"]/a/text()')
i, j = 0,0
csv = ""
delim = ";" #Разделитель
while i < len(name):
    print('Название новости:',name[i])
    print('Ссылка:',link_news[i])
    print('Количество комментариев:',end=" ")
    csv += name[i] + delim + link_news[i]+delim
    if link_news[i] in link_comments[j]:
        print(count_comments[j])
        csv += count_comments[j]
        j += 1
    else:
        print(0)
        csv += "0"
    i += 1
    csv += "\n"
    print()
with open("путь/для/сохранения.csv","w") as f:
    f.write(csv)
```

Comment: Попробую. Но мне кажется не так

Comment: Ну вы что-то усложнили себе задачу) количество комментариев на сайте уже давно и можно просто запарсить этот текст. В добавок добавил сохранение в csv

Comment: Знаю что можно, но происходит несоответствие колличества комментариев и заголовка новости. Допустим там где есть новость без комментариев, ей присваивается количество комментариев  другой новости

Comment: Как я и говорил количество комментариев не соответствует новости

Comment: Аа всё теперь понял вас

Comment: Обновил ответ, теперь думаю то что надо

Comment: Спасибо, попробую.

Comment: Немогли бы Вы добавить комментарий по выполнению условия "if" и в его теле

Comment: Ну смотрите, берутся ссылки на новости(link_news) и на их комментарии (link_comments), они похожи за исключением #comments в конце ссылок у комментариев. Как вы заметили есть так же 2 индекса, i указывает на индекс новости, j - на индекс комментарий. If проверяет есть ли часть ссылки на новость в ссылке на комментарии и если есть, то получается что есть комментарии на эту новость, если же эти ссылки отличны, то текущая ссылка комментариев к другой новости и указатель на неё оставляем в том же положении. (Сорян, не особо умею объяснять :) )

Comment: Например: link_news[i] = "/news/1234", а link_comments[j] = "/news/1235/#comments", здесь ссылка на новость не соответствует ссылке на комментарий, поэтому ставим данной новости 0 комментов и идём дальше. link_news[i] = "/news/1235", а link_comments[j] = "/news/1235/#comments". Тут уже ссылки совпали, можем брать количество комментариев по индексу j.

Comment: Огромное спасибо!!!

Comment: Как вы догадались до такого алгоритма? Как ?этому научится? Посоветуйте курсы и книги? Либо что то ещё?

Comment: Синтаксис и некоторые другие основы языка объяснили в универе, дальше учился по чужим примерам, с гуглом для конкретных вопросов и документацией. Преподы предлагали курсы и книги, но мне не очень заходит теория, поэтому ничего такого посоветовать не могу, извиняйте :)